# How to update Object's array's objects' value?

Tags: mongodb

Following code is not updating book title, how can achieve my goal of updating book title?

```
user: {
    _id: "123",
    books: [{ title: "ABC", pages: 99 }],
}

await model.updateOne(
    {
        _id: userID,
        "books._id": bookID,
    },
    { book: { title: "" } }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your scenario, you need [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters).

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "123" //userID
},
{
  $set: {
    "books.$[book].title": ""
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "book._id": "1"  //bookID
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FpS6wsEZT7W)

---

### References

[How the arrayFilters Parameter Works in MongoDB](https://database.guide/how-the-arrayfilters-parameter-works-in-mongodb/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
await model.updateOne(
    {
        _id: userID,
        "books._id": bookID,
    },
    { title: "" }
);
```